# several loops in only one loop with changing parameters over loops in R

Tags: r

Assume for illustration purposes that I have the following row vector `newdata.forgm[1,]`:

```
      X2       X3       X4       X5       X6       X7      X8       X9      X10     x11  
3.804125 4.480942 5.023256 5.453471 5.790166 6.048769 6.24211 6.380872 6.473965 6.528837

X12 ....     X36
6.55172....4.26642
```

where X1 was removed.

I want to create the following matrix with the following row vectors with 30 products each row:

```
(X2*X3)^(1/2)   (X2*X3*X4)^(1/3)      (X2*X3*X4*X5)^(1/4)  ... (X2*...*X32)^(1/31)
(X3*X4)^(1/2)   (X3*X4*X5)^(1/3)      (X3*X4*X5*X6)^(1/4)  ... (X3*...*X33)^(1/31)
(X4*X5)^(1/2)   (X4*X5*X6)^(1/3)      (X4*X5*X6*X7)^(1/4)  ... (X4*...*X34)^(1/31)
(X5*X6)^(1/2)   (X5*X6*X7)^(1/3)      (X5*X6*X7*X8)^(1/4)  ... (X5*...*X35)^(1/31)
(X6*X7)^(1/2)   (X6*X7*X8)^(1/3)      (X6*X7*X8*X9)^(1/4)  ... (X6*...*X36)^(1/31)
```

I have the following R code:

```
n=31
prod.spe <- function(x) {
    answ <- NULL
    for(i in 2:n) {
        answ <- c(answ, (prod(x[1:(i+0)]))^(1/i))
    }
    return(answ)
}
prod.spe(newdata.forgm[1,])


prod.spe <- function(x) {
    answ <- NULL
    for(i in 2:n) {
        answ <- c(answ, (prod(x[2:(i+1)]))^(1/i))
    }
    return(answ)
}
prod.spe(newdata.forgm[1,])

prod.spe <- function(x) {
    answ <- NULL
    for(i in 2:n) {
        answ <- c(answ, (prod(x[3:(i+2)]))^(1/i))
    }
    return(answ)
}
prod.spe(newdata.forgm[1,])

prod.spe <- function(x) {
    answ <- NULL
    for(i in 2:n) {
        answ <- c(answ, (prod(x[4:(i+3)]))^(1/i))
    }
    return(answ)
}
prod.spe(newdata.forgm[1,])

    prod.spe <- function(x) {
    answ <- NULL
    for(i in 2:n) {
        answ <- c(answ, (prod(x[5:(i+4)]))^(1/i))
    }
    return(answ)
}
prod.spe(newdata.forgm[1,])
```

How can I write ONLY one for-loop in R which accounts for the change in 0,1,2,3,4 and 1,2,3,4,5 (see above how these numbers change). Your feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You loops are extremely inefficient. Learn to pre-allocate. And then learn vectorization (i.e., you could use the `cumprod` function).

Comment: Sorry Roland, `newdata.forgm[1,]` is a row vector of numbers as you can see the matrix notation. newdata.forgm[1,] is a data.frame

Comment: Sorry, when editing it I made the mistake of duplicating it, but now it is fixed. Thanks Richard!

Comment: A previous solution that was proposed (and deleted) by Dominic finally worked. A parenthesis was just missing, but I figured that out. Thanks Dominic for your help!

Comment: So you start with 36, then drop a column (why?) so then 35 but you end up with 30 columns somehow?  And you're not planning to assign the results of all your loops to something but you want to magically get a matrix?

Comment: I actually get my matrix thanks to Dominic's suggestion and an extra implementation that I conducted. I drop why column purposely. I end up with 30 columns since that is my upper bound. These are geometric mean computations where each column represents a year. Thanks.

Comment: Hey np. I'm curious to see your solution, can you post it?

Comment: n=31
prod.spe1 <- function(x) {
  answ <- NULL
    for(i in 2:n) {
      for (j in 0:4) {
        answ <- c(answ, (prod(x[(j+1):(i+j)]))^(1/i))
          } 
    }
  return(answ)
}
matrix((prod.spe1(newdata.forgm[1,])),nrow=5,ncol=30)

Comment: I meant make an answer out of it (yes you can answer your own question on Stack Overflow, even accept it as the right one) - would be much more readable!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my question:

```
n=31
prod.spe1 <- function(x) {
asnansw <- NULL
for(i in 2:n) {
   for (j in 0:4) {
     answ <- c(answ, (prod(x[(j+1):(i+j)]))^(1/i))
       }
   }
return(answ)
}
matrix((prod.spe1(newdata.forgm[1,])),nrow=5,ncol=30)
```